# Show that $f$ has absolute minimum at $x=0$.

Tags: real-analysis

Given $f(x)=x^4(2+\sin(1/x))$ for $x\not=0$ and $f(x)=0$ when $x=0.$ Then we have to show that $f$ has an absolute minimum at $x=0.$

I have shown that $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ by considering $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x\to 0}x^3(2+\sin(1/x))=0.$$

So we have that $f'(0)=0.$ Also $f(0)=0$. I think that if I show that $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ then I might be done and so $$0\leq x^4\leq f(x)\leq 3x^4$$ and so $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$ we have that $f(x)\geq 0$ and so $0$ is the absolute minimum. However, I am not sure whether this reasoning is correct and so any inputs in this regard would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

If $x\ne 0$, $x^4>0$ and $2+\sin(1/x)\ge1$, so certainly $x^4(2+\sin(1/x))>0=f(0)$.